# Android M - GPS onLocationChanged issue

Tags: android, gps, location, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to get gps coordinates and I had the following:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

SessionManagement sessionManagement;
private Intent i;

static final Integer LOCATION = 0x1;
static final Integer GPS_SETTINGS = 0x7;

GoogleApiClient client;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
LocationManager locationManager;
String mProvider;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LOCATION);
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(AppIndex.API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    //locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //mProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
            + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Splash.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permission)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    client.disconnect();
}

private void askForGPS(){
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(client, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            Log.e("LOCATION", result.toString());
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(Splash.this, GPS_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        switch (requestCode) {
            //Location
            case 1:
                askForGPS();
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

It seems `onLocationChanged` never fired. What am I doing wrong? It's my first time with `checkPermission`.
Manifest has INTERNET and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Could anyone help me? It would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Runtime Permissions,in Android M and higher version of Android you need to give runtime permissions to your app.

now it doesn't matter that you have declared permissions in AndroidManifest.xml or not.

You can check this link for reference about [Android Runtime permissions.](https://learnpainless.com/android/marshmallows/runtime-permission-example-good-practice-real-example)

Comment: I did it. It asks for runtime permission and runtime check gives me permission granted